# Read an exact one struct field

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Here is the code to get system information:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class win{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SYSTEM_INFO{
        public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
        public ushort wReserved;
        public uint dwPageSize;
        public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
        public UIntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
        public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
        public uint dwProcessorType;
        public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
        public ushort wProcessorLevel;
        public ushort wProcessorRevision;
    };
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

    public static void Main(){
        var sysInfo = new SYSTEM_INFO();

        GetNativeSystemInfo(ref sysInfo);
        var res = sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture;
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Output is `9`.
Is there a way to read exact one struct field, without define all struct?

For example, get value of first field:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class win{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(IntPtr lpSystemInfo);

    public static void Main(){
        var sysInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(96);
        GetNativeSystemInfo(sysInfo);
        var res = Marshal.ReadByte(sysInfo, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Output is `9`. But how to get value of, for example, third field? May be there is some marker inside buffer, that can tell me, that new field begins?

Comment: The data is a blob of binary data. If you have two bytes (1, 2) and one int (0x100) then it would look like 01 02 00 00 01 00 in binary. There is no additional data present in the data telling you at which offset which data type is located. That is the job of the struct definition. You need to know at which offset is what located either by defining a struct or by manually hard coding all the offsets which is very error prone. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You are communicating with a C API. In C the structure of data is encoded in the type system. The type system is only available to the compiler. Once it is done there is no metadata left in the object code, at all. If you need to make sense out of that data you're going to have to replicate its structure in whatever language you are using. If you don't want to write the structure definitions yourself, check out [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get value of, for example, third field?

Just set the offset after the first two fields:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class win {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(IntPtr lpSystemInfo);

    public static void Main() {
        var offset = 4;
        var sysInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(offset + 4);
        GetNativeSystemInfo(sysInfo);
        var res = Marshal.ReadInt32(sysInfo, offset);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sysInfo);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Output: `4096` **(** dwPageSize **)**